# Using ruby to generate SHA512 crypt-style hashes formatted for /etc/shadow?

Tags: ruby, encryption, passwords, sha, crypt

I want to generate SHA512 hashed passwords for inclusion directly into a /etc/shadow file for use with [chef's user resource](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-User).  Normally I'd go to the stdlib's `Digest` library for this, but it doesn't generate the hash in the right format:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > require 'digest/sha2'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > Digest::SHA512.hexdigest('test')
 => "ee26b0dd4af7e749aa1a8ee3c10ae9923f618980772e473f8819a5d4940e0db27ac185f8a0e1d5f84f88bc887fd67b143732c304cc5fa9ad8e6f57f50028a8ff"
```

The format that the shadow file wants is:

```
$6$/ShPQNXV$HJnibH9lw01qtYqyJQiBf81ggJB2BGUvKA7.kv39HGCeE.gD4C/SS9zAf5BrwOv3VJzvl99FpHYli9E8jykRC0
```

Things I've looked at:

- The openssl "dgst" module returns the same format as .hexdigest, and its "passwd" module doesn't include SHA512 support.
- String#crypt, but that does not support SHA512. (edit: this is only the case on OSX - modern Linux distros will work if you specify "$6$somesalt" as the salt)
- [ruby-crypt](http://crypt.rubyforge.org/) gem, but it does not support SHA512

For comparison, something that does return the proper format is PHP's [crypt](https://www.php.net/crypt), but I'd rather not have to exec out to PHP for something that should be simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After further research:

- The mkpasswd command, which on debian is in the `whois` package (weird):

  mkpasswd -m sha-512
- String#crypt does actually call the platform's native crypt() call, however OSX (up to 10.6) does not include support for alternate ciphers.  "password".crypt('$6$somesalt') will work on Linux platforms.

Comment: I'd merge this with your question.

Comment: would be interested in a native ruby solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043017/how-to-convert-php-crypt-function-sha512-to-ruby