# How to convert php crypt function (SHA512) to ruby?

Tags: php, ruby, base64, sha512

**note: i am not looking for workaround, i am looking for a plain ruby solution!**

this question is the similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171487/using-ruby-to-generate-sha512-crypt-style-hashes-formatted-for-etc-shadow), but it isn't answerd, its just a workaround to a shell commando there.

i want to generate a sha512 encrypted string which is compatible with the format in debian /etc/shadow.

the following create a correct string with [php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php):

```
$salt = 'fGn9LR75';
$hash = crypt('test', '$6$'.$salt);
// hash is:
// $6$fGn9LR75$YpI/vJHjEhvrYp5/eUSRinpiXdMthCxFWSEo0ktFNUaRBsA7pCWYzzmQptmnfyHno9YEJFNHYuESj3nAQmSzc1
```

as far as i know this a normal, salted base64 encoded string. the spec of the sha generation method is [here](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt)

Comment: It looks like your shift key is broken.

Comment: no, i just prefer to write in lowercase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
irb(main):001:0> salt = 'fGn9LR75';
irb(main):002:0* hash = 'test'.crypt('$6$' + salt);
irb(main):003:0* hash
=> "$6$fGn9LR75$YpI/vJHjEhvrYp5/eUSRinpiXdMthCxFWSEo0ktFNUaRBsA7pCWYzzmQptmnfyHno9YEJFNHYuESj3nAQmSzc1"
```

The `crypt()` algorithm for SHA256/512 is *not* simply a base64-encoded hash. It's an intentionally crazy process which involves multiple hashes running in parallel.